# how to get a entire div to be clickable in ie8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

there are many articles and question on this but the issue is that I need the div and the link to be transparent as I have another dynamic content under it.

The below code works well in all browsers except ie 8,9 and 10. 
www.iamvishal.com/residen u an see the work here.

```
<div class="field-link">
<a href="http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31">http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31</a>  
</div>


jQuery(".views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row .views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row-item .field-link").click(function(){
 window.location=jQuery(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
 return false;
});
```

Comment: You must tell us what is going wrong specifically; and share error messages if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need javascript, just put the div inside the anchor:

```
<a href="http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31">
  http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31
  <div class="field-link"></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an `onClick` event

```
<div class="field-link" onclick="location.href='http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31';">
<a href="http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31">http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31</a>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you have an extra slash in your URL, and other browsers can deal with the bad URL but IE can't.

Instead of
http://www.iamvishal.com/residen//node/31
try
http://www.iamvishal.com/residen/node/31

Answer (score 0):

IE does not allow to have block anchors with transparent background. You should set background color to white and set opacity to 0:

```
.views-slideshow-cycle-main-frame-row-item .field-link a {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 295px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 797px;
  z-index: 300;
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

Comment: I tried this already using background white and then changing the opacity but it did not work for me.

Comment: That's strange because it works for me on your site. Try to position absolutely not the `anchor` but `div`. Set `div's` fixed height. Then set height to 100% on anchor.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant this is my code based on ur comments http://pastebin.com/HMD0Fr06

Answer (score 0):

A common solution to this problem is to have two anchor tags in your div. The first is a basic tag with the actual text. The second is an tag with a class that gives it the transparent block overlay rules.

This enables your site to continue to function for the lowest common denominator.